# Data Structure with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am trying to create this nested hash structure as as FactoryGirl Object, so that I can call `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:my_object)`

```
amount: total,
payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce],
device_data: params[:device_data],
customer: {
  first_name: params[:first_name],
},
billing: {
      first_name: params[:first_name],
      last_name: params[:last_name],
}
```

So far I have

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_object do
    amount nil 
    payment_method_nonce '132465'
    device_data 'device_data'
    customer {
      first_name 'Richard' 
    }
    billing {
      first_name 'Richard'
      last_name 'Lewis' 
    }
  end
end
```

I am getting syntax errors and can't seem to get it right

Answer (score 4):

Factory girl uses `{}` in it's syntax.  You need [two sets to get a hash](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#lazy-attributes).

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_object do
    amount nil 
    payment_method_nonce '132465'
    device_data 'device_data'
    customer { 
      {
        first_name: 'Richard' 
      }
    }
    billing {
      {
        first_name: 'Richard',
        last_name: 'Lewis' 
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: because `{}` here is a block.

Comment: Thanks :-) makes sense